# How to select and deselect a svg line and change its color on selection and deselection using d3.js and javascript , jquery?

Tags: jquery, select, d3.js, colors, line

I am building a Mind Mapping software , where whenever I draw a line and select it by clicking on it, its color should change.At this time all other lines or svg elements that are previously selected should get deselected and their color should change to their original color.

Following is my code:

```
function drawLine()              
{

$(document).ready(function(){   



var line;

var l = d3.select("body").select("svg#svg_canvas").on("mousedown",        mousedown).on("mouseup", mouseup);




function mousedown() {

var m = d3.mouse(this);
line = l.append("line")
    .attr("class","l1")
    .attr("x1", m[0])
    .attr("y1", m[1])
    .attr("x2", m[0])
    .attr("y2", m[1]);


l.on("mousemove", mousemove);
}

function mousemove() {
var m = d3.mouse(this);
line.attr("x2", m[0])
    .attr("y2", m[1]).on('click',function(){        

d3.selectAll(".selected").classed("selected", false);
$(this).css({'stroke':'#000'});
d3.select(".selected").remove();
if(d3.select(this).classed("selected"))
{

d3.select(this).classed("selected", false);

}else{

 d3.select(this).classed("selected", true);
 $(this).css({'stroke':'#FC5CEF'});
}   
});

}


function mouseup() {
l.on("mousemove", null);
}

})


}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either store the previously selected lines globally and change whenever those lines when current line is selected or maintain css class name between the two states.